# Save Image Displayed in IE - Authentication Issue

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

In Excel, I am trying to write a piece of code that will launch IE, go to a specific URL and then automatically save the image that is displayed in IE.  I am able to launch IE, manually log into the website loaded in IE and then have IE go to a specific URL, but I cannot figure out how to get it to save the image that is displayed in the browser.

When I look at the TestDownload.jpg that the code downloaded, the image cannot be viewed. When I open the TestDownload.jpg file with Notepad++, it reveals that the image file is actually an HTML file that is the login page for the website.

Is URLDownlaodToFile not using the authenticated session that exists in the IE instance which was launched using VBA and manually logged into?

This is the code that I currently have.

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If


Private Sub LaunchIE()

'Set a reference (Visual Basic Editor) > Tools > References) to the following libraries:
  ' a) Microsoft Internet Controls
  ' b) Microsoft HTML Object Library

  Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
  
  Dim HTMLdoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
  Dim HTMLelement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

  With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Silent = True 'avoid any pop-up
    .navigate "https://mywebsite.com/login"
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
  End With
  
  
 'Give user 20 seconds to accept cookies and log into website with 2FA.
 If Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")) = True Then
    MsgBox "20 Second Wait Over"
End If

  With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Silent = True 'avoid any pop-up
    .navigate "https://myfiles.mywebsite.com/api/v1/get_photo?filename=photo_ab1c234d-56ef-7890-g5h4-32ijk210l31m.jpg&application_id=1234"
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
  End With
 
  Call DownloadCurrentImage
 
End Sub

Private Sub DownloadCurrentImage()
    
    Dim Downloaded As Boolean
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim Index As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim NameParts As Variant
    Dim Values As Variant
    Dim MyURLImage As String
    
    MyURLImage = "https://myfiles.mywebsite.com/api/v1/get_photo?filename=photo_ab1c234d-56ef-7890-g5h4-32ijk210l31m.jpg&application_id=1234"
    
    FileName = "TestDownload.jpg"
       
    Const DownloadPath As String = "C:\MyFiles\Images\"
    
    Downloaded = URLDownloadToFile(0, MyURLImage, DownloadPath & FileName, 0, 0) = 0

    
End Sub
```